# Spring boot app when shutting down doesnt disallow new incoming connections but abruptly exits

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I have a spring boot app which creates a thread that monitors idle time before calling SpringApplication.exit() to terminate the app on being idle for a long time.. And i have a restcontroller class which serves web requests..

The issue is that even after SpringApplication.exit() is called, the controller seems to accept the incoming connections for a small window of time before the app itself exits. And this results in the client abruptly being terminated, when a new incoming connection is accepted by controller and then the earlier call to SpringApplication.exit() takes effect and makes the app exit.

//pseudo-code

```
@RestController
public class AppController {

  @PostMapping("/testproc")
  public ExitStatus process(@RequestBody Job testJob) {
    logger.info("Job batch Id passed: {}", testJob.batchId);
    //do processing
    if(shutdownFlag) {
        //report error to client
    } else {
        //do regular processing
    }
  }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ctx = SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    Thread shutdownThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                  //check for some condition
                  if(shutdownFlag) {
                       logger.info("Exiting");
                       SpringApplication.exit(ctx, () -> 0);
                       return;
                  }
             });

    shutdownThread.start();
  }
}
```

logs generated:

```
2019-03-23 02:02:46.439  INFO 13484 --- [      Thread-10] c.i.e.newgenv1.svc.MyApplication   : Exiting
2019-03-23 02:02:46.441  INFO 13484 --- [      Thread-10] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6660a289: startup date [Sat Mar 23 02:02:29 IST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-03-23 02:02:46.509  INFO 13484 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2019-03-23 02:02:46.665  INFO 13484 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 156 ms
2019-03-23 02:02:47.559  INFO 13484 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] c.i.etl.newgenv1.svc.AppController  : Job batch Id passed: 23
2019-03-23 02:02:53.828  INFO 13484 --- [      Thread-10] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

Pls note the lines logged.. The line "Exiting" generated by shutdown thread happens before Controller picks up a connection and prints batch id

I either need to stop the controller from picking up new connections or report an error code to the client during these times. But the issue is that controller picks up the connection but before it could report error, the app exits..

I even tried graceful shutdown logic outlined here: https://dzone.com/articles/graceful-shutdown-spring-boot-applications

but still it doesnt help..

Comment: the lifecyle of the raw Thread you create cannot be managed by Spring automatically. If you want to have spring manage it, use springs ExecutorService, which should be automatically configured. see here for an example: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-and-threads-taskexecutor

Comment: I dont want to manage the lifecycle of the thread. I want to ensure that when SpringApplication.exit is called, no more new connections are accepted by the controller.. Thats the issue iam facing

Comment: yes, exactly. you don't want to manage the lifecyle yourself, which is why you want to use Springs ExecutorService, so Spring manages it for you

Answer (score 1):

You can add an interceptor which will check if shutdown is initiated. If not, the flow will continue it's normal execution else the requests should be dropped and proper response should be sent.

Comment: How do I intercept and how do I send the response when the process itself has exited ?

Comment: The Process has not fully exited thats why the controller's are still getting executed.
So you can add an interceptor which will intercept all the request URLs (*) and in its "preHandle" check if "shutdownFlag" is set to true.
If its true, then populate a proper error message and response code and throw an error to client.

Comment: In fact, iam doing the checking of shutdown flag and sending of error response inside the controller instead of a specific interceptor.. I detect the shutdown flag inside the controller and send it.. But the problem is, the process is running when the connection is accepted by the controller, but before the controller could send the response, the process exits.

Comment: nevertheless.. can you give me a sample code which i can try